# Minecraft Custom Block Modding

Tags: java

I;m getting an error when trying to register my blocks, the error i'm getting is as follows:

The method registerBlock(BufferBlock) is undefined for the type GameRegistry
The method registerItem(BufferItem) is undefined for the type GameRegistry

package com.elitedire4k.immersivesignals;

```
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

@Mod(modid = Main.MODID, name = Main.NAME, version = Main.VERSION)
public class Main
{
    public static final String MODID = "immersivesignals";
    public static final String NAME = "Immersive Signals";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    @SidedProxy(clientSide = "com.elitedire4k.immersivesignals.ClientProxy", serverSide = "com.elitedire4k.immersivesignals.CommonProxy")
    public static CommonProxy proxy;

    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event)
    {
        GameRegistry.registerItem(BufferItem.instance);
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(BufferBlock.instance);

        proxy.preInit();
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        proxy.preInit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that forge’s API can change on a daily basis, you should probably post the version. Also my guess is that they changed the register method to simply “register”.

Comment: ok so i changed the lines to register and imported what was needed, but now i get another error: it's the latest one forge 1.12.2-14.23.2.2611

Comment: this is the new code for that line : @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event)
    {
     Item register = GameRegistry.register(BufferItem.instance);
     Block register2 = GameRegistry.register(BufferBlock.instance);
        
        proxy.preInit();
    }.....it gives me this problem : The method register(K) from the type GameRegistry is not visible

Comment: I scrapped that code, gonna start over.